# C memory allocation initialising and handling

Tags: c, memory-management, pointer-arithmetic

Having trouble with my task here. I need to create a global block of free memory and malloc it. Having some trouble initialising it due to typecast and handling errors.

Like arrays in C where the first array is actually a pointer to the first element, my memory block needs to be similar where i can use pointer arithmetic to locate blocks of memory.

```
//global variable
static byte *memory = NULL;

void allocator_init(u_int32_t size){

     *memory = (byte*) malloc(size);
}
```

The addresses/pointers to these memory addresses will be stored via structs/links as headers of the memory block.

```
typedef struct _header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    header* next;
    header* prev;
} header;
```

Comment: If you have included the header `<stdlib.h>` the cast is redundant; if you haven't the cast hides a nasty bug ... or you are better off without the cast whether you included the proper header :)

Comment: I did, its included at the top

Answer (score 5):

Drop the `*`:

```
*memory = (byte*) malloc(size);
^
```

You might also want to drop the cast but that's your call.

Comment: "You might also want to drop the cast but that's your call." - if it's C++, then not. If it's C, then also not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @H2CO3 I once read a post by an illustrious SO user who said there are pros and cons to casting the result of `malloc` in C.

Comment: @H2CO3 Definitely not. I can't remember who it was or I would have named him/her.

Comment: then I don't argue :) (Seriously, it only makes code unreadable and error prone in case you forgot to include stdlib.h...)

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't cast either but I also don't directly advise other people to do the same.

Comment: If you "need" the pointer casting, probably you are not compiling C (but C++)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the return value of malloc to the pointer itself, not to the byte pointed to by the pointer. (Anyway, if you dereference the initially NULL pointer, your program will segfault.)

```
memory = malloc(size);
```

Also, don't caat the return value of malloc.

Answer (score 1):

`*memory = (byte*) malloc(size);` - This statement means you are trying to assign the address of the heap memory block as a value to `*memory`. Here `memory` is having `NULL`, so it will crash.

You have to assign the addres to the variable like, `memory = (byte*) malloc(size);`

Comment: so will global static take care of assigning variable memory to be used as a pointer??

Comment: No. you have to assign the addess return by `malloc` only to the variable `memory` even if it is local variable also.

Answer (score 0):

In your header struct, since the struct references itself, declare the internal header pointers as "struct _header * name;". I think other people have hit all the other points :)